# Does it exist a function to preserve the elements in the set

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a set of n numbers let's say A = {1,2,..,n}
I am going to perform a subtraction on the set using a number m. Is there a formula f, so that after the subtraction is done, I get a result r in the set A?
For example:
I have the set {1,2,3,...,12} representing 12 months of the year
I would like to look for the previous month... normally subtracting m from the set above by 1 is fine but when it is January, I would like it to go back to 12 (December)... I believe it should exists some similar formula but I can not wrap my head around it... modulus(m-k,12)? m being the month, k being an arbitrary of previous months? It does not work all the time. Does such a formula exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, but you need to know modular arithmetic. The formula is $$f(k) := k-m \pmod n$$

So if we say Januar is $0$ and December is $11$ then $$f(0) = 0-1 = 11 \pmod{12}$$

Comment: That's it! I knew it has something to do with the modulus but I just can not make it right! Thank you so much!

Comment: My only issue is that in mathematics $\pmod n$ is not an operation.  It's as statement about how numbers relate.

Comment: Yeah, it more like in some computer program... @fleablood